# Recover Images / Data from Dead VMWare ESXi Box

Tags: esxi

## tl;dr;

How do I mount drives that use the VMFS file system such that I can get data off of them?

---

I have an old (ESXi 4) machine. The mother board died.

I am not going to rebuild another ESXi machine. Instead, I am just going to repurpose an old laptop and use it as a NAS device for the house.

I have taken the hard drives out of the old ESXi machine and now would like to get the data off of them.

Ideally, I would like to be able to mount those drives in another machine, spin up the various virtual machines, and copy the data I want to keep to another location.

Windows, though, doesn't seem to be able to mount these drives. They use a file system called VMFS (VmWare File System). Short of trying to install ESXi on some other machine, is there another way I can mount these drives and gain access to the content there-in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can Google is to use [VMFS Tools](https://glandium.org/projects/vmfs-tools/).

Requires a Linux box, but it looks like it will work pretty well. Have not tried yet.

---

Just using fvmfs on its own will allow you to view a read-only mount of your drives (as described [here](https://www.petri.com/access-vmfs-volumes-without-vmware-host)).

Again, this is read-only and will not allow you to spin up the virtual machines to copy data off of them.

Hoping once the images are copied locally, I will be able to bring them up using Virtual Box.